# Import data into existing table, unique entries

Tags: excel, statistics, data-analysis

I need to do some aggregation and statistics on data and I'm thinking about doing that with Excel as the raw Data already comes in Excel format. Basically you could say it's kind of a log type of data with Datetime and some more information on each line.

I'm not yet clear what aggregation and other stuff needs to be done on this data but I already know that I need to merge new data into the then existing excel sheet every day or two. There is no real unique identifier in the data but the combination of 2 or more fields could easily be used for uniqueness. I wonder if there's a smart way to import the new data from time to time even if it contains already existing data then. Maybe something like copy it into a new tab/sheet then start some kind of import action where uniqueness gets checked?

I'm unsure if this can be done with Excel at all so please bear with me if the question sounds stupid to excel pro's.

Comment: Yes, you can do this in Excel using VBA.

Comment: Thanks, any hint to get further down that road, @Carol?

Comment: without seeing your file and data I can only drop ideas. You can open your new data file using GETOPENFILENAME. Then have a button which triggers a VBA macro. In the VBA macro, loop for each row of the new raw data. Check if it already exists in the output sheet by using FIND. If it does, ignore it (I assume), if it doesn't exist, add a new row to the end of the output sheet. Loop until finished all raw data. close your raw data file without saving changes.

Answer (score 0):

Assume in a worksheet columns A and C can be combined for uniqueness. You could concatenate them to create an id:

```
In D2 = concatenate (A2,C2)
```

Then, add another worksheet of data, with this same concatenated column D added.

Then, add a third worksheet with a formula to only show unique data rows:

```
In worksheet 3 A2: =if(countif(sheet1!d:d,sheet2!d2))>0,"",sheet2!a2
In worksheet 3 B2: =if(countif(sheet1!d:d,sheet2!d2))>0,"",sheet2!b2
In worksheet 3 c2: =if(countif(sheet1!d:d,sheet2!d2))>0,"",sheet2!c2
```

This will create a sheet of unique ids with some rows (those that are unique) populated. You could copy and paste this as values only, the sort by any of the headings to get at the unique data only.

This is not the most efficient way to do this at all, but it will work in a pinch.